# Savon: Wrong Element Name Prefix. How can I change it?

Tags: ruby, soap, savon

So here is the code that I have:

```
resp = client.call(
  :producer_query,
  message: {
    'cmn:Carrier'            => '',
    'cmn:ProducerCriteria' => { 'cmn:EntityType' => 'Individual',
                            'cmn:CustomerId' => 5555,
                             :attributes! => {'CustomerId' => {'type' => 'AGENTCD'}}},
    'cmn:SectionConfiguration' => { 'cmn:SectionType' => 'Associations', :attributes! => {'cmn:SectionType' => {'activeOnly' => 'false'}}},
    :attributes!            => { 'cmn:Carrier' => { "id" => 55555 }}
}
) do
    wsse_auth ENV['ID'], ENV['PASSWORD'], :digest
  end
```

And it produces something that looks like:

```
<soapenv:Body>
    <cmn:ProducerQuery>
      <cmn:Carrier id="5555"/>
      <cmn:ProducerCriteria>
        <cmn:EntityType>Individual</cmn:EntityType>
        <cmn:CustomerId>55555</cmn:CustomerId>
      </cmn:ProducerCriteria>
      <cmn:SectionConfiguration>
        <cmn:SectionType activeOnly="false">Associations</cmn:SectionType>
      </cmn:SectionConfiguration>
    </cmn:ProducerQuery>
</soapenv:Body>
```

I've added in the 'cmn' to everything, but the ProducerQuery to make it match what I think it should be. However, I think it really should read 'tran' instead. I can control the 'cmn' for everything but the part that reads `<cmn:ProducerQuery>`. How can I make it read `<cmn:ProducerQuery>`?

Comment: What are you asking exactly? Namespace prefixes shouldn't really matter so long as they're defined. There are no namespace declarations in your XML..

Comment: I'm totally new to SOAP, so forgive my ignorance. How would I know if there are no namespace declarations? Are you talking about something like this: `xmlns:tran="http://domain.com/schemas/2006/06/Transaction.xsd` in the envelope?

Comment: yes. your elements would then need to be prefixed with 'tran', eg. <tran:ProducerQuery>..</...>

Comment: Or you specify the default namespace like this `Savon.client(namespaces: { 'xmlns' => 'http://domain.com/schemas/2006/06/Transaction.xsd' })` and drop the prefixes

Comment: @SteffenRoller how do I specify that? All I pass in to the call method is a symbol `:producer_query` and it looks like Savon takes it from there.

Comment: @DavidK-J, I'll take a look at doing that.

Comment: Thank you both! I figured it out. What I actually did was change it to `xmlns:cmn="http://domain.com/schemas/2006/06/Transaction.xsd` You both gave me a missing piece. I didn't realize you could change the namespaces to match what Savon was generating.

Comment: for completeness: I believe I answered that question about how to define additional namespaces here before: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21346353/387177